# SQL: Get first entry in aggregation function?

Tags: firebird

I have a simple table:

```
ID - JID - AMOUNT 
1  -   1 - 100
2  -   2 - 50
3  -   2 - -25
4  -   3 - 100
5  -   3 - -50
```

I want to end up with:

```
JID - FIRSTBALANCE
1   - 100
2   - 50
3   - 100
```

Because Firebird is so insanely difficult when it comes to aggregation, this doesn't work:

```
SELECT jid, amount as firstBalance
FROM table
GROUP BY jid
```

How can I get it so it groups by JID, and automatically set the value of firstbalance to the first value in the table?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This is what I was looking for:

```
SELECT jid, max(amount) as firstBalance
FROM table
GROUP BY jid
```

Comment: No, it is not what you were looking for. You were looking for first value from where aggregation starts not the maximun value.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what do you mean with "automatically set the value of firstbalance to the first value in the table". From the example of the desired result you gave I thought you consider the row with lowest `ID` value for given `JID` group as "first" so

```
SELECT DISTINCT JID, 
   (SELECT amount FROM table s WHERE s.JID = o.JID ORDER BY s.ID ROWS 1)
FROM table o
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Firebird does not contain a `first()` or a `last()` aggregate function. This has been requested and denied by the team due to which item would be chosen. You'd need to specify an `order by` clause for the items that get aggregated.

The answer you selected gets you the `max(amount)` not the `first(amount)`. This is not what you asked for (though possibly it is what you wanted).

For future Googlers/Bingers here's how you get the first item. It's not a terrific solution, and it can be slow.

```
select distinct a.jid,
      (select first 1 b.amount
       from table b
       where b.jid = a.jid
       order by b.id) as amount
from table a
order by a.jid
```

It will retrieve the three JID fields and the first found amount as determined by ID order.

Don't hold your breath for this to get built into Firebird. When asked about a positional aggregate in the past, the response was:

"*I have a great deal of trouble with that concept because position isn't a relational concept and the introduction of positional operators will signficantly inhibit efforts to improve performance by performing operations in parallel.*"